# How do you combine these sentences using proper relative pronouns?

Tags: grammar, pronouns

I have this sentence:
"She asked six of her employees to come to the meeting. Four of them turned up."

I tried combining the sentences this way:

"Six of her employees were asked to come to the meeting, four of whom turned up."

Apparently, it is wrong.

May anyone explain to me how should I proceed and where lies the mistake?

Comment: Please explain why you think that there is a mistake anywhere in what you have written here.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "She asked six of her employees to come to the meeting, four of whom turned up." It's perfectly understandable, and it's clear that "whom" has "four of her employees" as its antecedent.

Answer (score 1):

Your recasting is grammatically correct and sounds natural but doesn't have all the information that's in the version on which it's based (specifically, it doesn't say who asked the employees to the meeting), which is probably why it was deemed incorrect. Perhaps better is "She asked six of her employees to come to the meeting, four of whom turned up.", though personally I'd leave it as two clauses, perhaps separated by a semicolon instead of the original period.